# Kotlin. Coroutines: How to run repeatable job?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, delayed-job

I need to make api call before until the server sends a success status. The request must be executed with a delay of two seconds, and all this must be done until 10 seconds have elapsed.

Here are my attempts:

```
suspend fun loadData(): Data {
    try {
        withTimeout(10000) {
            val data = repository.getData()
            if (data.status == "SUCCESS") {
                // complete
            } else {
                delay(1000)
                // and after delay I need again call repository.getData(), until the status is SUCCESS
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // complete
    }

}
```

But I do not understand how to loop the execution of the request and it seems to me that something is wrong with my code. Perhaps there is a more concise way, please help me.

Comment: you can use `while`

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use a simple `while` loop for that:

```
suspend fun loadData(): Data? {
    return try {
        withTimeout(10000) {
            var data = repository.getData()
            while (data.status != "SUCCESS") {
                delay(1000)
                data = repository.getData()
            }
            return@withTimeout data
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        null
    }
}
```

Comment: @sergpetrov, it will not complete after 10 seconds ?

Comment: @sergpetrov, it might be possible to use while (isActive) ?

Answer (score 2):

Alternate solution using a flow. I think it makes it cleaner to do this while being able to handle exceptions thrown from `getData()` while continuing to retry. In your original code, it looks like you are going to give up the first time an exception is thrown by `getData()` instead of continuing to retry every 1000ms.

The return type has to be nullable to handle the case where it isn't retrieved in time.

```
suspend fun loadData(): Data? {
    return withTimeoutOrNull(10000) {
        flow { 
            while(true) { 
                emit(repository.getData())
                delay(1000)
            }
        }
            .retry { delay(1000) }
            .first { it.status == "SUCCESS" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach with `repeatWhen` of `flow` without `while` loop:

```
suspend fun loadData(): Data? {
        return withTimeout(10000) {
            flow {
                val result = repository.getData()
                if (result.status == "SUCCESS") {
                    emit(result)
                } else throw ServerException()
            }.retryWhen { cause, _ ->
                if (cause is ServerException) {
                    delay(1000)
                    true
                } else false
            }.singleOrNull()
        }
}
```